# Is there an English translation of Jordan's "Cours D'analyse"

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I am trying to find an English translation of Camille Jordan's work "Cours D'analyse". Only the French edition is on Amazon, so since this is a somewhat specialized topic, I thought perhaps someone in this forum might know.

TIA,
Matt

Comment: I am fairly certain that no "widely circulated" English translation exists, but it's possible a translation may have been carried out as a Masters' thesis of which one or two typewritten copies exist in a library somewhere. For anyone interested in studying Jordan's work (which I've been told was very influential in transmitting Cantor's work in point set theory to Borel and other French mathematicians during the late 1880s and early 1890s), [Helene Gispert's 1982 Ph.D. Dissertation on Jordan's treatise](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/gispert.pdf) is freely available on the internet.

Comment: Indeed it is. And it too, is in French :(

Comment: I can almost barely just about read French, usually enough to know whether something might be of interst to me, so I can definitely sympathize. I included the Gispert reference here because I thought it would be useful to archive that information here for those in years to come who stumble on this question while looking for information about Jordan's treatise.

Comment: With google Chrome Translate ( syntax may be not ok) and commonality  with English math vocabulary a lot may be understood and  guessed for a start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just discovered that you can open an online version of it in Google Chrome and have google translate it to English:

http://archive.org/stream/coursdanalysede13jordgoog/coursdanalysede13jordgoog_djvu.txt

Answer (score 8):

During 1989 I spent several months translating all 3 volumes for my own benefit.  About a decade later I spent several more months creating Word files using MathType.  If you would like to proof read Chapter 1 of Volume 1 then contact me.

Comment: Thank you for the information!  I would very much like to proof chapter 1. You can send it to mtbrenneman@gmail.com. I really look forward to reading it.

Comment: @NormanBarrett Do you plan on publishing the translation at some point?

Comment: @NormanBarrett what is the best way to contact you regarding Camille Jordan's book ?

Answer (score 3):

There is, translated by Robert E. Bradley (Professor of Mathematics at Adelphi University) and C. Edward Sandifer (Professor of Mathematics at Western Connecticut State University). You can find it [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441905480).

EDIT: this is incorrect. See comments :)

Comment: This is Cauchy's treatise, not Jordan's treatise. FYI, there are several French mathematical textbook treatises with this same (or almost exactly the same) title that appeared in the 1800s.

Comment: Ahahahahahaha I feel like such a fool. Well, I'll leave the answer up so people can see these comments and not make the same mistake. That said, Cauchy was among the most intelligent individuals in history, and I imagine his treatise is likely worth a read as well :)

Comment: FYI, I got a copy of Bradley/Sandifer's book right after it was published. In fact, I may have placed my order before it was actually available.

Comment: Well, I just finished The Mathematician's Apology and am eager for a new read, so I will certainly check it out!